# How to give effect on dragging in CSS or through jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raving/so2fdqjs/) in my project. I want to show some effect while dragging the item. This example shows drag effect on text while dragging. I want to give effect to the background as well as the text. what should I need to do to give effect.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.ui-drop-hover {
    border: 2px solid #bbb;
}

#dragdiv li, #dropdiv li {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#dropdiv li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#maindiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 2px solid #bbb;
}

#allItems, #Ul1 {
    list-style: none;
}

#dragdiv, #dropdiv {
    width: 180px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
}

#allItems li {
    background: #3195e0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It is setting the background of the list not on the dragging of item.

Comment: You can set `.ui-draggable-dragging` class anyway you like in your css. This is the one for the item being dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line of css code done job for me

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
```

Hope this help you